# in java using regular expressions replace + and - with " + " and " - "

Tags: java, regex

in java im trying to use `string.replaceall` to  replace "+" and "-" with " + " and " - "

However `str.replaceall("+"," + ")` results in an error,
so I tried `str.replaceall("\+"," + ")` and `str.replaceall("\Q+\E"," + ")`

neither worked

after that i tried str.replaceall("\+"," + ") but forgot to mention it originally, but it does not affect my strings which contain "1x^5+2x^4+6x^3+3x^2+4x^0"

Final answer =

            `str = str.replaceAll("\\+"," + ");

            str = str.replaceAll("\\-", " - ");`

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, slash and backslash are not the same character. :)

Comment: was an error when posting to stackoverflow used correct slashes in the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a regex, just use `str = str.replace("+", " + ").replace("-", " - ");`

Note that since strings are immutable, you need to use the returned string, hence the str = ...

Comment: turned out it was a combination.  
         str = str.replaceAll("\\+"," + ");  
         str = str.replaceAll("\\-", " - ");

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
str.replaceall("\\+"," + ")
```

Answer (score -1):

Final answer =

`str = str.replaceAll("\\+"," + ");

str = str.replaceAll("\\-", " - ");`